# Uniform convergence with sine functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n = \sin(\frac{3n}{4n+5}x) $ as $f_n:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $. 
I try to determine if $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on the open intervals $I_1=(0; 1)$ and $I_2(1; \infty)$. 
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $n_0>0$. 
$f_n$ is uniformly convergent, iff 
$$\forall x \in I: |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$ 
I figured out that $$f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(f_n(x))=\sin(\frac{3}{4}x)$$.
So it follows:
$$\forall x \in I: \biggl|\sin\Bigl(\frac{3n}{4n+5}x\Bigr)-\sin\Bigl(\frac{3}{4}x\Bigr)\biggr| < \epsilon $$
But how do I find out about $\epsilon $? 
How do I find out, if it's really uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 2):

That sequence converges uniformly to $f$ on $(0,1)$. In fact, since $\sin'=\cos$, and since $|\cos|$ is bounded above by $1$, you have$$(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R):|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leqslant|x-y|.$$So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\left|\frac{3n}{4n+5}-\frac34\right|<\varepsilon$. And then, if $x\in(0,1)$ and $n\geqslant N$,$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{3n}{4n+5}x\right)-\sin\left(\frac34x\right)\right|\leqslant\left|\left(\frac{3n}{4n+5}-\frac34\right)x\right|<\varepsilon.$$

However, your sequence does *not* converge uniformly on $(1,\infty)$. Can you see why?

Comment: I don't really see why.
Is it because there is an $x \in (1,\infty)$ that wouldn't satisfy $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: It's because, given $n\in\Bbb N$, you can always find some $x$ such that $\frac34x\in\pi\Bbb Z$ and that $\frac{3n}{4n+5}x\in\frac\pi2+\pi\Bbb Z$.